# Python Generic vs Object Type Hint

Tags: python, generics, types

In python, you can create a generic type using `TypeVar`:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

def my_function(a: T) -> T:
    return a
```

However, you can also represent an object of any type using `object`:

```py
def my_function(a: object) -> object:
    return a
```

Both types are similar, but `TypeVar`s provide something objects don't: They allow you to specify that one type in two places is the same type. `my_function` using the `T` type hint for its `a` parameter and its return says that the return type of `my_function` will be the same as the type of the `a` parameter. On the other hand, `object` does not say this.

So, in this example, `TypeVar` is clearly better than `object`. But what about in cases where the type only appears once:

```py
def my_function(a: T) -> str:
    return str(a)
```

```py
def my_function(a: object) -> str:
    return str(a)
```

?

In this case, both types are identical, right? Which one should be used, and why?

Comment: Saying `a: object` to me is a uglier way of saying `a: Any`. The version in the first example `def my_function(a: T) -> str:` will get a warning that a typevar is incorrectly used, because a generic function has to return the same type as the input.

Comment: So, the first version is wrong, the second is correct but strange and I'd use `Any` type instead.

Comment: Using Any has a disadvantage: inside the body of the function, no typechecking happens on that variable.  If you use either `object` or `T` you’ll get warnings about treating it as a narrower type unless you narrow it with `isinstance` checks.

Comment: @NotAName `a generic function has to return the same type as the input` - can you please cite where this is stated? `The version in the first example [...] will get a warning that a typevar is incorrectly used` - what do you mean? I ran the first example in [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net) and it ran successfully, with no warnings.